# Failing to Import Files Compiled from Protobuf in Python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, protobuf-python

My directory structure is as follows:

```
 test
 |-test.py
 |-test.proto
 |-test_pb2.py
 |-__init__.py
 |-comm
    |-comm.proto
    |-comm_pb2.py
    |-__init__.py
```

both __init__.py is empty
and **test.proto** is like this:

```
package test;
import "comm/comm.proto";

message Test{
    optional comm.Foo foo = 1;
}
```

and **comm.proto** is like this:

```
package comm;

message Foo{}
```

i successfuly used command *protoc --python_out=. -I. comm.proto*  in **comm** directory to compile  **comm.proto** and *protoc --python_out=. -I. test.proto* in **test** directory to compile  **test.proto**
but when i tried to import ***test_pb2*** in ***test.py***, i encounter this error

```
TypeError: Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool: Depends on file 'comm/comm.proto', but it has not been loaded
```

Can someone help me identify the reason and provide a solution, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I think how `protoc` works with Python is more complicated|confusing than the average bear! My recourse is to use Golang to see what its SDK does and then reverse engineer that back into Python.

The documentation says that `protoc` ignores Protocol Buffers packages. See [Defining your Protocol Format](https://protobuf.dev/getting-started/pythontutorial/#protocol-format) and the note:

> The .proto file starts with a package declaration, which helps to prevent naming conflicts between different projects. In Python, packages are normally determined by directory structure, so the package you define in your .proto file will have no effect on the generated code. However, you should still declare one to avoid name collisions in the Protocol Buffers name space as well as in non-Python languages.

I'm unfamiliar with Python Packages and Modules but ...

1. `package`'s

When you define a `package` in a proto file, convention is that the proto file be in a folder that matches the `package` name. You can see this with e.g. [Google's Well-known Types](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/) and e.g. [`Timestamp`](https://protobuf.dev/reference/protobuf/google.protobuf/#timestamp). This is defined in [`timestamp.proto`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/src/google/protobuf/timestamp.proto) to be in `package google.protobuf` and so it's in the a folder path `google/protobuf` and, by convention, it's called `timestamp.proto` (though the file name is arbitrary).

Because `message Test` is in `package test` and `message Foo` is in `package comm`, the structure would be more correctly (!?) structured as:

```
.
├── comm
│   └── comm.proto
└── test
    └── test.proto
```

When you use `protoc`, you must define `--proto_path` for each distinct folder that contains `package` folders. In this case `--proto_path=${PWD}` which can be omitted.

2. `protoc`

This gives `protoc`:

```bash
protoc \
--python_out=${PWD} \
--pyi_out=${PWD} \
test/test.proto \
comm/comm.proto
```

> **NOTE** I encourage you to include `--pyi_out` to get "intellisense" in Visual Studio Code.

Or, my preference is to be more emphatic and include the root (`${PWD}`) of the proto `package`'s:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD} \
--python_out=${PWD} \
--pyi_out=${PWD} \
${PWD}/test/test.proto \
${PWD}/comm/comm.proto
```

3. Python packages

Curiously, even though we were told that the `package` would not have an effect on the Python code, it does. The `package test` proto is output to `test` folder and `package comm` to `comm` folder.

You will need to create an empty `__init__.py` in `test` (but not `comm`) for the code to work.

4. Empty `Message`

Your `comm.Foo` message is empty (`{}`) and so there's nothing to use.

I tweaked it:

```
package comm;

message Foo{
    optional string bar = 1;
}
```

5. Basic Python example

```
import test.test_pb2

test = test.test_pb2.Test()

test.foo.bar = "Hello"

print(test)
```

Yields:

```
foo {
  bar: "Hello"
}
```

6. `protos` folder

My recommendation is to use a folder e.g. `protos` to hold proto sources, i.e.

```bash
.
└── protos
    ├── comm
    │   └── comm.proto
    └── test
        └── test.proto
```

And then e.g.:

```bash
protoc \
--proto_path=${PWD}/protos \
--python_out=${PWD} \
--pyi_out=${PWD} \
${PWD}/protos/test/test.proto \
${PWD}/protos/comm/comm.proto
```

> **NOTE** `--proto_path` extends to include `protos` and `protos` must be prefix on the proto sources **but** the generated code is still by `package` in `${PWD}`

```
.
├── comm
│   ├── comm_pb2.py
│   ├── comm_pb2.pyi
├── main.py
├── protos
│   ├── comm
│   │   └── comm.proto
│   └── test
│       └── test.proto
└─── test
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── test_pb2.py
    └── test_pb2.pyi
```

This has the advantage of being more universally applicable if you decide to generate e.g. Golang sources too.

Comment: I was inspired by your response, and then I followed these steps to solve my problem: 
1. In the "test" directory, use the "protoc --python_out=. comm/comm.proto" command to compile "comm.proto." Instead of using the "protoc --python_out=. 
 comm.proto" command to compile "comm.proto" in the "comm" directory.
2. "import comm/comm.proto" first in test.py

Using the "protoc --python_out=. comm/comm.proto" command and the "protoc --python_out=. comm.proto" command to compile the proto, there will be some differences in the "comm_pb2.py" file.